# How to sort with PHP Toolkit

Tags: php, sorting, search, netsuite, toolkit

I've been working with NetSuite PHP Toolkit to create saved searches, but I can't seem to figure out a way to sort the results on a certain column. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to sort SuiteTalk search results. The only way to sort results is to page through all of the results and sort them client side.